# jquery is printing the code in the page? but it is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I decided to change my jquery version. It was the 1.12.0 to 3.10.0.

Everything is working fine, except this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var msg = '.text-holder';
    $('.time').timeago();
    $(msg).autosize();

});
</script>
```

this script is in the first line of one .php file, it is to show a date function. This .php is called by another js script. I can't make this date function work without this code inside the php called by ajax.

in jquery version 1.12 it works normally. Now it prints the code when the php page loaded by ajax shows, but the date function works, even it printing its code.

what is wrong?
can I use .on instead ready? will it work?